# Is this limit monotomic? n/ (e^n+14n)

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{n}{e^n+14n}$$

lim x approaches infinity is $$\frac{x}{e^x+14x}$$

Using L'Hopital's rule, I get lim x approaches infinity $$\frac{1}{e^x+14}$$

Thus, the limit would be 0. The graph of $$\frac{n}{e^n+14n}$$ seems to be monotomic increasing but I am not sure how to find the least value by which it is bounded above M.

Comment: Please edit your question with proper MathJax.

Comment: Please post what you have already tried. This is not a site to get your homework done for you.

Comment: Hint:$e^{\infty}=\infty$ and $\frac{1}{\infty}=0$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:$\dfrac{n}{e^n+14n}=\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{e^n}{n}+14}$

What is the limit of $\dfrac{e^n}{n}$?of $\dfrac{e^n}{n}+14$? what about its inverse?

Comment: The limit would be infinity for e^n/n. Then would the limit be 0?

Comment: totally! you can see it on the first fraction, as e^x grows significantly faster than x and 14n so $\frac{n}{e^n+14n}\sim\sim \frac{1}{e^n}$